# Json eval not able to parse data

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php program where I just test some sample data. I am getting error as missing `]` after element list. How can I read this?

```
$dataDetailsList = array();
array_push($dataDetailsList, array('a' =>'1','b' =>'2','c' =>'3','d' =>'4','e' =>'5'));
echo json_encode(array("DataDetailsList"=>$dataDetailsList));
```

Then in my jQuery processor I am doing like this.

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'live-server-data.php',
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(json);
            var jsonData = eval(" (" + data + ") ");
        },
        cache: false
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) is evil.
Instead of this use:

```
JSON.parse(data); // not supported in IE7 and below
```

I think you need to try

```
dataType: 'json'
```

That is,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'live-server-data.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var jsonData = data;
        console.log(jsonData);
        $.each(jsonData.DataDetailsList, function(key, val) {
             var key = Object.keys(val)[0],
                 value = val[key];
             console.log(key); // output: a, b, c ...
             console.log(value); // output: 1, 2, 3,...
            // alternative
            for(var key in val) {
                console.log(key);
                console.log(val[key]);
            }
        });
    },
    cache: false
})
```

Comment: Ok it works now how can I further process the data now? for(i=0 ;i <jsonData.DataDetailsList.length; i++) I am trying like this but can I know the associate name too by doing some processing here?

Comment: @user837306 that means to want to get `a`, `b` etc

Comment: JSON.parse is not supported in IE7. All other browsers current and previous releases support this... if IE7 is a concern you will have to shim it. just an FYI. +1

Comment: Yes I want to get what is a,b etc. The a,b,c can also be dynamic too.

Comment: I add this alert(key); after the console it give me 0?

Comment: Ok it works but only first data as a 1 I know cause u put [0] how to get for all the other key and values.

Comment: @user837306 check my update and if it doesn't work properly, then make a fiddle with the `data` object and provide it here

Comment: IT works perfectly. Let me do some more testing and then get back to you thank you very much for your help. So should I stick to this or go with json2?

Comment: @user837306 Welcome stick with it

Answer (score 4):

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'live-server-data.php',
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(json);
            var jsonData = data;

        },
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json' //data type that it will return 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just set the `dataType` to json and jQuery will do the trick for you..

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'live-server-data.php',
    dataType: 'json',  //Added dataType json
    success: function(data) {
        //Now data is a javascript object (JSON)
    },
    cache: false
});
```